# antlr difference between two rewrite rules ID INT and ^(INT ID)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

In the antlr documentation, I see the two following rules but their description sounds exactly the same.  What is the difference between these two rules...

```
a : INT ID -> ID INT ; // reorder nodes
a : ^(ID INT) -> ^(INT ID) ; // flip order of nodes in tree
```

Also, why not write the second rule like this or would that be the same as the first rule then and so there is no difference between the rules?

```
a : ^(INT ID) -> ^(ID INT) ;
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `^(INT ID)` means `INT` is the root, and `ID` the child.
- `INT ID` means both `INT` and `ID` are child nodes.